# how can set address of libraries in Cmakelist

Tags: c++, c, cmake, gtk3, clion

I'm a beginner in CMake and the ways that can use it. My IDE is Clion and I tried to install gtk3 for c++ and follow all of the instructions but the simple sample code that they suggest for the test is not work for me. you can find the instructions [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gtkmm/MSWindows). this is the code:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv);

    Gtk::Window window;
    window.set_default_size(600,400);

    return app->run(window);
}
```

the error is `fatal error: gtkmm.h: No such file or directory` but when I change the `#include <gtkmm.h>`to `#include <gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm.h>` I did not get the error anymore here but I got an error in other subheaders like `fatal error: glibmm.h: No such file or directory`. it just needs to somehow tell the compiler to look in the subdirectory but I don't know how to do it. I think it can be fixed in the CmakeLists.txt file but I don't know how to do it. this is my CmakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(gtk)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(gtk main.cpp)
```

please if anybody knows it helps me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we encourage to **search** before asking a question. "I think it can be fixed in the CmakeLists.txt file but I don't know how to do it." - Have you tried to search on this topic? Many questions on Stack Overflow already contain `CMakeLists.txt`, have you tried them? E.g. [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37301250/cmake-error-with-gtkmm).

Comment: To use CMake, you need to write a CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730135/how-do-i-link-gtk-library-more-easily-with-cmake-in-windows

Answer (score 2):

You are not linking to the gtk library properly.

You need to use [`find_package()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) in your CMakeLists.txt as shown below:

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GTK REQUIRED gtk+-3.0)

include_directories(${GTK_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GTK_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${GTK_CFLAGS_OTHER})

add_executable(gtkdemo main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(gtkdemo ${GTK_LIBRARIES})
```

For further information, you may refer to the following:

> ['undefined reference to' when using GTK with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56387754/undefined-reference-to-when-using-gtk-with-cmake)

> [How do I link gtk library more easily with cmake in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730135/how-do-i-link-gtk-library-more-easily-with-cmake-in-windows)